# How to return a pruned yaml tree with only the top few levels in yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I'd like to return a simplified, filtered yaml document based on some nested keys. I haven't yet found how to accomplish this, but given how powerful [mikefarah/yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) is, I'm confident it is doable.

Given input:

```yaml
ns-a:
  name-a:
  -
    prop-a: "aye"
    prob-b:
      stuff: "that doesn't matter"
    target-prop: "just-me"
  -
    prop-a: "aye"
    target-prop: "not-me"
  name-b:
  -
    prop-a: "aye"
    target-prop: "just-me"
  -
    prop-a: "aye"
    prob-b:
      stuff: "that doesn't matter"
    target-prop: "not-me"
ns-b:
  name-a:
  -
    prop-a: "aye"
    target-prop: "just-me"
  -
    prop-a: "aye"
    prob-b:
      stuff: "that doesn't matter"
    target-prop: "not-me"
  name-b:
  -
    prop-a: "aye"
    target-prop: "just-me"
  -
    prop-a: "aye"
    prob-b:
      stuff: "that doesn't matter"
    target-prop: "not-me"
```

I would like to return:

```yaml
ns-a:
  name-a:
  -
    target-prop: "just-me"
  name-b:
  -
    target-prop: "just-me"
ns-b:
  name-a:
  -
    target-prop: "just-me"
  name-b:
  -
    target-prop: "just-me"
```

Where the structure remains intact, but only the `target-prop` is exposed and only when it is "just-me".

I can sort of accomplish this with [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), but this is not the ideal way to deal with structured data.

```
rg -N '^\w|^  \w|target-prop: "just-me"' tmp.yaml
```

Yields:

```
ns-a:
  name-a:
    target-prop: "just-me"
  name-b:
    target-prop: "just-me"
ns-b:
  name-a:
    target-prop: "just-me"
  name-b:
    target-prop: "just-me"
```

Close, but no cigar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update `|=` at the second level `.[][]` by reducing the array items to objects only containing the desired key using `pick`, then `select` those that match in content, and take the first using `.[0]` (structurally, there could be more than just one, as in your sample):

```bash
yq '.[][] |= (map(pick(["target-prop"]) | select(.[] == "just-me")) | .[0])'
```

```yaml
ns-a:
  name-a:
    target-prop: "just-me"
  name-b:
    target-prop: "just-me"
ns-b:
  name-a:
    target-prop: "just-me"
  name-b:
    target-prop: "just-me"
```

Tested with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) v4.34.2

Comment: Outstanding! That works as expected.